# Enable Tomcat access logging in GraphDB

Tags: graphdb

I would like to enable Tomcat access logging in GraphDB embedded Tomcat. Does anyone know if this is possible, and eventually how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a specific reason to use Tomcat logging you can use instead GraphDB own audit logging. It does basically the same thing plus options like logging for specific headers and other.

http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/security-auditing.html

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, @KonstantinPetrov! We have tested GraphDB audit logging, and it seems to fulfill our requirements.